# How can I use selectize in an input form in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, selectize.js

Suppose I have an input field: `<input type="text" placeholder="Select Teams" />` and I should be able to select `Support` by clicking the input field.

[image]

and then

[image]

I learned that this is possible using [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). How should I be able to incorporate it as a vue directive?

Comment: You should wait for a component change. Check out https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/events.md and https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md (specifically `onItemAdd`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Vue.directive('selectize', function(el, binding){
  var options = binding.value || {}
  $(el).selectize(options)
})
```

Then use `v-selectize` directive where you want.

You can also add more options. For example:

```
<input v-selectize="{maxItems: 3}" type="text" placeholder="Select Teams" />
```